# Using rpm to install linux kernel and i get some Failed dependencies which is newer than the yum list ones

Tags: centos, kernel, installation, yum

### i am trying to upgrade kernel on centos and i use rpm to install the kernel.rpm,i got some errors

```
[datacenter@fonova-app-dc01 ~]$ sudo rpm -ivh kernel-
3.10.327.3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
warning: kernel-3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    module-init-tools >= 3.16-2 is needed by kernel-3.10.0-
    327.3.1.el7.x86_64
    grubby >= 8.28-2 is needed by kernel-3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64
    dracut >= 033-283 is needed by kernel-3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64
    linux-firmware >= 20150904-43 is needed by kernel-3.10.0-
    327.3.1.el7.x86_64
    /usr/sbin/new-kernel-pkg is needed by kernel-3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64
[datacenter@fonova-app-dc01 ~]$ sudo yum update
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
[datacenter@fonova-app-dc01 ~]$ sudo yum list module-init-tools 
Installed Packages 
module-init-tools.x86_64      3.9-26.el6                 @base
```

[datacenter@fonova-app-dc01 ~]$

---

erro says that i need module-init-tools >= 3.16 but when i type

---

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum list module-init-tools
```

---

it says that hte newest version of module-init-tools is 3.9.
why will it be like this??

Comment: have you tried any other version of the kernel ? and have oyu looked at the kernel-ml option (Which will bring you a fully up to date kernel (4.x)?

Comment: This looks more suitable for https://serverfault.com/ perhaps.